# How to return multiple string variables from a single SQL Select Statement in Asp.Net/C# Codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

For example, using following code.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) as 'ClientActive', 

(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM t1 AS t2 WHERE t2.fieldname = 'A') AS TotalA,

(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM t1 AS t2 WHERE t2.fieldname = 'B') AS TotalB,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM t1 AS t2 WHERE t2.fieldname = 'C') AS TotalC,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM t1 AS t2 WHERE t2.fieldname = 'D') AS TotalD
 FROM t1 WHERE clientstatus='active'
```

I want something return like this:

```
    lblString1.Text = TotalA;
    lblString2.Text = TotalB;
    etc..
```

Can someone produce a C# code to do this? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know there is no COUNT(number) but COUNT(columnName) or COUNT(*)

Comment: @Steve, there is `COUNT(number)` but it is same as `COUNT(*)`, there is no difference.

Comment: Oh well, always good to learn something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DataSet then loop through it or just get the first row and assign each row value to the label (assuming you know how to fill a dataset):

```
lblString1.Text = row["ClientActive"].toString(); lblString2.Text = row["TotalB"].toString(); etc.
```

Comment: I've created a dataset and added row["TotalA"] and it works. Thank you.